# Errno 13 while running docker-compose up

Tags: python, django, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose

I'm building an application using django and I wanted to add docker to this project.

I'm trying to run

```
sudo docker-compose up
```

Which gives me this output:

```
ERROR: .IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './docker-compose.yml'
```

I checked the permissions using GUI. Everything is fine.

I'm trying to run my app from an mounted drive. I also tested it on other drives. The only drive this problem does not appear is my main drive running Ubuntu 18.04.

Looking forward to some answers

Comment: Why are you running it with sudo?

Comment: It fixed something. Unfortunately I can't reproduce it.

Answer (score 11):

I found a working solution.

Don't use the snap installation and do this instead (tested Ubuntu 20.04)

```
apt install docker.io docker-compose
```

Answer (score 10):

adding the directory where I am running my `docker-compose.yml` using the apparmor reconfigure tool:

```
$ sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor
```

Comment: Had to run `sudo apparmor_parser -r /var/lib/snapd/apparmor/profiles/snap.docker.compose` afterwards to reload the apparomr profile for this snap

Comment: It didn't help me, let's try the answer above: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55305211/529442

Answer (score 4):

You need to update your AppArmor configuration :

Snap Dockers are heavily controlled with AppArmor.

To diagnose if it is really the case, check the last lines of the syslog after you triggered the error :

```bash
dmesg | grep docker-compose
```

You should see a snap.docker that was denied:

> kernel: [ ] audit: type=1400 audit(....):
>   apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="snap.docker.dockerd"
>   name="/bin/kmod" pid=7213 comm="exe" requested_mask="x"
>   denied_mask="x" fsuid=0 ouid=0

To correct this, just go to apparmor config's tunables :

```
cd /etc/apparmor.d/tunables
```

And edit HOMEDIRS variables in the 'home' file, for example from :

```
@{HOMEDIRS}=/home/
```

to

```
@{HOMEDIRS}=/home/ /media/aUser/Linux/
```

hope that helps.

Comment: This worked for me, thanks. For some reason running `sudo dpkg-reconfigure apparmor` in the other answer didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

All the other answers didn't work for me.

docker --version

> Docker version 20.10.17, build 100c701

docker-compose -v

> docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown

Instead of

> docker-compose up

please use

> docker compose up