# docker error: .IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "./docker-compose.yml"

Tags: docker, docker-compose, permission-denied

I am a complete beginer when it comes to docker and I am trying to install a webserver aplication called steve via docker (https://github.com/RWTH-i5-IDSG/steve). I followed the instructions corectly, however when i use the command "`*docker-compose up -d*`", I get the folowing error:

> ERROR: .IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: "./docker-compose.yml"

I am runing the latest version of ubuntu 18.04 and so far i have tried the folowing:
-Using "`sudo docker-compose up -d`" (same error)
- using "`sudo docker build`" (builds correctly but i still cant start it)
-changing the permisions of both the dockerfile and docker-compose.yml to 777
- changing the file owner to root

The files are completly unchanged from the source code.
I have only found a few users with this error who have posted an answer and none of them have worked so i am making my own question. I apologise for my bad English.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix docker: Got permission denied issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48957195/how-to-fix-docker-got-permission-denied-issue)

Answer (score 14):

- When running a simple command like `docker ps` or `docker run hello-world`, Are you facing any issues?
  If the answer is yes, please do the following on your ubuntu environment.

  - Create a group (if it doesn't exist) - `sudo groupadd docker`
  - Add your user to the group - `sudo gpasswd -a $USER docker`
  - If using a server - you must log-out from your session and reconnect to the server.
  - Validate that it is working with `docker run hello-world`

Comment: Thank your for your replay. Docker has no issues with those comands and i also tried to add the user to the group but the issue persists. I tried some other commands and it seems only docker-compose comands have the error.

Comment: Can you get more logs via `docker-compose logs -f` and post it here?

I think it was already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53344380/errno-13-while-running-docker-compose-up.

Comment: The solution in the comment from Feb 3 '20 worked, thanks a lot!

Comment: Please note that adding a user to the docker group gives that user root privileges.  See the warning here: https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/