# .PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './docker-compose.yml' Jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a problem. It's pretty serious, and it's not logical at all, so let's get started. I want to build and deplocate an application into a docker container. For this I wrote dockerfile and docker-compose:
**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:14-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: always
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
```

In fact, that's it. Now I need to set up the Pipeline in Jenkins, but I will make a precondition. When I run the build, Jenkins gives me an error:

**.PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './docker-compose.yml' Jenkins**

The Pipeline I had was this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Test"'
            }
        }


        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                sh 'sudo docker-compose up -d'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The simplest Jenkins file, but it gives the error I described earlier. I tried putting sudo, it doesn't help either. Here is my jenkins file at the moment, which should solve this error, but it still doesn't:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'npm install'
            }
        }

        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'echo "Test"'
            }
        }


        stage('Deploy') {
            steps {
                   sh 'chmod +x /home/panic/.jenkins/workspace/Jenkins-testing/jenkins/scripts/deploy.sh'
                   sh 'sudo chmod +r ./docker-compose.yml'
                   sh 'sudo chmod +x ./docker-compose.yml'
                   sh 'docker-compose version'
                   sh 'sudo docker ps'
                   sh 'whoami'
                   sh 'id'
                   sh 'ls -l docker-compose.yml'
                   sh 'sudo -u jenkins cat ./docker-compose.yml'
                   sh 'sudo chmod +rx ./docker-compose.yml'
                   sh 'sudo chown jenkins ./docker-compose.yml'
                   sh 'sudo -u panic cat ./docker-compose.yml'
                   sh 'sudo chmod 777 ./docker-compose.yml'
                   sh 'sudo chmod 777 docker-compose.yml'
                   sh 'sudo chown jenkins:jenkins docker-compose.yml'



                sh 'sudo docker-compose --log-level debug up -d'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Everything above **docker-compose up -d** works fine. User **panic** (my user), has a docker group. **jenkins** has the same.
Also, I installed the **Docker Pipeline** plugin, but it doesn't help. I hope you can help me, the error is not clear at all.
My logs:

```
Started by user admin
Obtained Jenkinsfile from git https://github.com/panic08/lapay-payment-frontendd
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /home/panic/.jenkins/workspace/Jenkins-testing
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Checkout SCM)
[Pipeline] checkout
Selected Git installation does not exist. Using Default
The recommended git tool is: NONE
No credentials specified
 > git rev-parse --resolve-git-dir /home/panic/.jenkins/workspace/Jenkins-testing/.git # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://github.com/panic08/lapay-payment-frontendd # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://github.com/panic08/lapay-payment-frontendd
 > git --version # timeout=10
 > git --version # 'git version 2.34.1'
 > git fetch --tags --force --progress -- https://github.com/panic08/lapay-payment-frontendd +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 63012060962a8cc6c2dd54d0602740cfc5cfad97 (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 63012060962a8cc6c2dd54d0602740cfc5cfad97 # timeout=10
Commit message: "v4.0"
 > git rev-list --no-walk 76360bec99e46802a993c3645755eb703e58dee1 # timeout=10
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Build)
[Pipeline] sh
+ npm install

up to date, audited 1514 packages in 11s

236 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

6 high severity vulnerabilities

To address all issues (including breaking changes), run:
  npm audit fix --force

Run `npm audit` for details.
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test)
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo Test
Test
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Deploy)
[Pipeline] sh
+ chmod +x /home/panic/.jenkins/workspace/Jenkins-testing/jenkins/scripts/deploy.sh
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo chmod +r ./docker-compose.yml
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo chmod +x ./docker-compose.yml
[Pipeline] sh
+ docker-compose version
/snap/docker/2746/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:32: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography. The next release of cryptography (40.0) will be the last to support Python 3.6.
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
docker-compose version 1.29.2, build unknown
docker-py version: 5.0.3
CPython version: 3.6.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.1.1  11 Sep 2018
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
[Pipeline] sh
+ whoami
panic
[Pipeline] sh
+ id
uid=1000(panic) gid=1000(panic) groups=1000(panic),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),110(lxd),1001(docker)
[Pipeline] sh
+ ls -l docker-compose.yml
-rwxrwxr-x 1 panic panic 137 Apr 12 20:26 docker-compose.yml
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo -u jenkins cat ./docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: always
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo chmod +rx ./docker-compose.yml
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo chown jenkins ./docker-compose.yml
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo -u panic cat ./docker-compose.yml
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    restart: always
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo chmod 777 ./docker-compose.yml
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo chmod 777 docker-compose.yml
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo chown jenkins:jenkins docker-compose.yml
[Pipeline] sh
+ sudo docker-compose --log-level debug up -d
/snap/docker/2746/lib/python3.6/site-packages/paramiko/transport.py:32: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.6 is no longer supported by the Python core team. Therefore, support for it is deprecated in cryptography. The next release of cryptography (40.0) will be the last to support Python 3.6.
  from cryptography.hazmat.backends import default_backend
Using configuration files: ./docker-compose.yml
.PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: './docker-compose.yml'
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
ERROR: script returned exit code 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

**Update**
My catalogs:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JivPs.png)

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66255373/3730626) can help